# Pipe tail output via elinks

Tags: linux, bash

Consider the following command:

```
elinks -dump file.html
```

It will print the file, formatted as plain text (without HTML tags).

The file.html is constantly updated and I want to run it through "tail -f like this:

```
tail -f file.html | elinks -dump
```

However it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: `The file.html is constantly updated`. Meaning that it will be appended to the file or the file will be overwritten again and again?

Answer (score 2):

`tail -f` only prints lines which are newly added to the end of the file.

If you want to check the output of the command in certain intervalls, `watch` can do that:

```
watch elinks -dump file.html
```